# Linear Algebra - inverse of a complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is from the UPenn prelim questions. http://hans.math.upenn.edu/amcs/AMCS/prelims/prelim_review.pdf

(question 12 in Linear Algebra session)

Let A be a real symmetric matrix and form the matrix

$R(z) = (z I - A)^{-1}$

for complex values of $z$ whenever it is defined. Then the question is to prove that the elements of $R(z)$ are quotients of two polynomials in $z$ whose denominators have zeroes of at most first order. I wasn't quite sure why this is so. Is it something that just follows from some linear algebra theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the spectral theorem there's an orthogonal matrix $O$ such that
$$A=ODO^T$$ where $D=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ is diagonal so

$$R(z)=(zI-A)^{-1}=O(zI-D)^{-1}O^T=O\operatorname{diag}\left(\frac{1}{z-\lambda_1},\ldots,\frac{1}{z-\lambda_n}\right)O^T$$

Comment: You forgot some $O$ and $O^T$.

Comment: I fixed the typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What if $A$ were the diagonal matrix $\Lambda$? What allows you to reduce to that case?